# Optimize large numpy array multiplication with sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am doing a statistical calculation of the following form:

[image]

where

- **d** (data) is a matrix of size [i=30, 100x100]
- **m** (model) is a matrix of size [i=30, 100x100]
- **C<sup>-1</sup>** (covariance) is a 100<sup>2</sup> by 100<sup>2</sup> symmetric matrix

**d** and **C<sup>-1</sup>** are constants and do not have any structure apart from **C<sup>-1</sup>** being symmetric. **m** changes, but is *always sparse*.  The output of the calculation is just a floating-point number.

I need to perform this calculation many times in a Monte Carlo simulation, so speed is of the essence.  Using sparse array multiplication techniques with **m** speeds things up considerably over a naive matrix dot product.  However, each iteration of the slow function below still takes about 0.1 seconds to run.  The vast majority of time (>98%) is spent in the matrix multiplications, and not the model generation function (`generate_model`).  I would like to speed this up by an order of magnitude if possible.

The code and output are pasted below.

Things that do **not** work include:

- Upgrading to the Intel MKL linear algebra routines (few percent speedup, surprisingly small)
- Using `numpy.linalg.multi_dot`
- Taking advantage of the fact that **C<sup>-1</sup>** is symmetric (this does not work even in principle, see [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82858/fast-multiplication-of-constant-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-and-vector))

Things that **sort of** work include:

- Precalculating **C<sup>-1</sup>d**, gives a ~40% speedup

**How can I speed up this code?**  Solutions relying on packages like `cython`, `numba`, etc are most welcome as well as "standard" scipy/numpy solutions.  Thanks in advance!

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import sys 
import timeit

def generate_model(n, size, hw = 8): 
    #model for the data--squares at random locations
    output = np.zeros((n, size, size))
    for i in range(n):
        randx = np.random.randint(hw, size-hw)
        randy = np.random.randint(hw, size-hw)
        output[i,(randx-hw):(randx+hw), (randy-hw):(randy+hw)]=np.random.random((hw*2, hw*2))
    return output

def slow_function(datacube, invcovmatrix, size):
    model = generate_model(30, size) 
    output = 0 
    for i in range(model.shape[0]):
        data = datacube[i,:,:].flatten()
        mu = model[i,:,:].flatten()
        sparsemu = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(mu)
        output += -0.5* (
                  np.float(-2.0*sparsemu.dot(invcovmatrix).dot(data)) +
                  np.float(sparsemu.dot(sparsemu.dot(invcovmatrix).T))
                  )   
    return output

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 100 
    invcovmat    = np.random.random((size**2, size**2))
    #make symmetric for consistency
    invcovmat    = (invcovmat+invcovmat.T)/2
    datacube     = np.random.random((30, size, size))
    #TIMING
    wrapped = wrapper(slow_function, datacube, invcovmat, size)
    times = []
    for i in range(20):
        print i
        times.append(timeit.timeit(wrapped, number = 1)) 
    times.sort()
    print '\n', np.mean(times[0:3]), ' s/iteration; best of 3'
```

Output:

```
0.10408163070678711  s/iteration; best of 3
```

Comment: I think `numpy.linalg.multi_dot` just tries to decide if one sequence of `dot` is faster than another, based on how quickly it reduced array sizes.  It doesn't help all the array dimensions are about the same.

Comment: My experience is that creating a `csr` matrix is relatively expensive.  Sparse dot improves speeds if the sparsity is on the order of 10% or less.  Also sparse dot is best when all arrays are sparse.  In fact if one of the arrays is dense it might first densify the sparse one and do a regular dot.

Comment: That's true, but casting it to a sparse matrix does pay off in this case.  The sparsity is about 2-3% (16^2 elements out of 10000 ~2.5%).

Comment: Which GPU do you have? I expect that such kind of algorithm provides good speed, if implemented on the GPU in the right way.